# How to process p:inputText change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, primefaces

I am using p:inputText and my requirement is to fire a javascript function, that would update the backing bean searchField

```
<p:inputText required="true" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.searchTip}" value="#{cc.attrs.queryProperty}" />

<p:remoteCommand name="resetSearch" actionListener="#{searchBean.resetSearch}" process="@this" />
```

And here is my javascript function. I used firebug to find the id of inputText element and thats page:j_idt18:searchForm:j_idt20_input. Id is correct for sure

```
$("#page:j_idt18:searchForm:j_idt20_input").change(function() { 
    alert("Its here");
    if(!this.value) {
       resetSearch();
       } 
});
```

It looks fine to me, but when I edit my search field, by adding or deleting then alert is not fired. Main requirement is to call backing bean, when user uses backspace button to make the search field empty.

I checked id of inputText element and wrote a javascript function

My question is, how can I write javascript/jquery function, who constantly monitor any changes in the searchfield(p:inputText).

Comment: Code in your question is missing a `}` for the if condition, is that a typo?

Comment: `$('yourPelement').on('input', function() { // do something } );`

Comment: The javascript call is inside $(document).ready(function()

Comment: are you looking for this - https://jsfiddle.net/nd3fL2cn/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per jquery selector Docs:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar")

Hence, You need to escape special characters in ID

```
$("#page\\:j_idt18\\:searchForm\\:j_idt20_input").change(function() { 
  alert("Its here");
  if(!this.value) 
    resetSearch();
});
```

or use attribute equals selector to target element having special character in it:

```
$("[id='page:j_idt18:searchForm:j_idt20_input']").change(function() { 
  alert("Its here");
  if(!this.value)
     resetSearch();
});
```

Comment: missed `}` in if statement?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo and Milind is indeed correct. I replaced with his code and its working fine :-) \\ were needed before every :

Comment: @Sandra: glad it helps. :) 
don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write javascript/jquery explictly you can use `p:ajax` for your requirement as :

```
  <p:inputText required="true" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.searchTip}" 
     value="#{cc.attrs.queryProperty}" >        
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{searchBean.resetSearch}" />
    </p:inputText>
```

event will be fire whenever user types and going to next component.

Comment: Problem is that I want to resetSearch only when the value is empty, empty searchField. In your solution, it will resetSearch field all the time, users edit anything. My alert message was kind for debugging the issue to correctly identifying the id of the element, which I later removed from the code.